# Not able to figure out the logical error in my code

Tags: c, string, infix-notation

There is some logical error in my code but I'm not able to figure out what it is. When I run my code it doesn't give me desired results.

OUTPUT:

```
Enter an infix expression
2+3
2
```

I get 2 as my postfix expression whereas I should be getting 23+.
Please see if anyone could help me out with this one.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#define max 20
int top=-1;
char infix[max],postfix[max],stack[max];
char pop();
int empty();
void push(char );
int precedence(char );
void infix_to_postfix(char * ,char * );

void main()
{
clrscr();
printf("Enter an infix expression\n");
gets(infix);
infix_to_postfix(infix,postfix);
printf("%s",postfix);
getch();
}

void infix_to_postfix(char infix[max],char postfix[max])
{
int i=0,j=0;
char value,x;
for(i=0;infix[i]!='\0';i++)
{
value=infix[i];
if(isalnum(value))
{
postfix[j]=value;
j++;
}
else
{
if(value=='(')
push('(');
else
{
if(value==')')
{
while((x=pop())!='(')
{
postfix[j]=x;
j++;
}
}
else
{
while(precedence(value)<=precedence(stack[top])&&!empty())
{
x=pop();
postfix[j]=x;
j++;
}
push(value);
}
}
}
}

while(!empty())
{
x=pop();
postfix[j]=x;
j++;
}
postfix[j]='\0';
}

void push(char x)
{
if(top==max-1)
printf("stack overflow\n");
else
{
top++;
stack[top]=x;
}
}

char pop()
{
char x;
x=stack[top];
top--;
return x;
}

int empty()
{
if(top==-1)
return(0);
return(1);
}

int precedence(char value)
{
if(value=='(')
return(0);
if(value=='+'||value=='-')
return(1);
if(value=='*'||value=='/'||value=='%')
return(2);
return(3);
}
```

Comment: Do you have any specific portion of code that you know is causing a problem? People will be less inclined to help if you publish your entire program and ask them to debug it for you.

Comment: That is what i dont know. Assuming that my logic is correct the progrom should give me desired result. I feel that my logic correct but I'm not able to figure out where is my program going wrong ?

Comment: Yeah, but you can't treat StackOverflow as a free debugging service. It helps if you have a specific portion of code that you need reviewed.

Comment: I myself reviewed this program many times.Im not able to find any mistakes.All i can do is wait for someone to review this code and help me out.

Comment: Your code is unreadable. Please indent it.

Comment: 'All i can do is wait' what?  Are you unable to use a debugger at all?  Do you collapse if you try to edit in some extra var dumps to trace what is going on?   Is it some medical condition, some phobia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, the logic of your code is OK except a return value mistake in the `empty()` function.
In the `empty()`, it should return 1 while stack is empty.

```
  int empty(){
     if(top==-1)
        return(0);  <-- !!! here should return 1
     }
```

Otherwise,

1. it will go into the while loop at `while(precedence(value)<=precedence(stack[top])&&!empty())` even when stack is empty.
2. And then `postfix[j] = x` may write a redundant `0`(now top= -2) to `postfix` array.
3. Finally,under the input `2+3`, the `postfix[]` will be `{'2','\0','3','+',...}`, which result in the abnormal output `2`.

So, it will work after modifying the `empty()` function, such as

```
int empty()
{
    if(top==-1)
       return(1); // not return(0)
    return(0); 
}
```

Output:

```
Enter an infix expression
2+3
23+
```

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is change your `empty()` function
 you are checking for `!empty()` in if condition, but you are returning 0, when it is empty, this will make the condition true, i.e. Stack is not empty. Change the return value to 1 in case of empty stack.